# yii, i am getting sql error when using restful api

Tags: rest, yii, yii2

I am writing restful API with Yii, but I am getting an SQL error in create function. My purpose is to add new data to the `news` table, but it asks me for the author_id. How can I do it without crushing the default create method?

[image: module file]

[image: controller file]

[image: Error]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, post the code itself, see the [help] section as to why.

Comment: What is `author_id`? Does it point to the `id` field on the `user` table? Do users need to authenticate to create `news`? If yes to all these questions, you could use `BlameableBehavior` to automatically populate the `author_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.** Run this below query on mysql/phpmyadmin and restart server

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

**Solution 2.**
Open the  my.ini or my.cnf file for editing (the file you have depends on whether you are running Windows or Linux).

Find the following line:
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Replace it with the line below:

If the line is not found, insert the line under the [mysqld] section (if there is no [mysqld] section, create it).

sql_mode= ""
Restart the MySQL service for the change to take effect.

If restarting is not a feasible option at the moment, you may log into the database server and execute the below command for the changes to take effect immediately. However, the change will be discarded the next time the MySQL service restarts unless the above process is performed.

set global sql_mode='';